# error in creating a file in PHP using file handling functions?

Tags: php

someone could please tell why this code does not work? it does not create data.txt. and the file does not save anything.

```
<?php
        $txt = "data.txt";

        if(isset($_POST['info1']) && isset($_POST['info2']) && isset($_POST['info3']) && isset($_POST['info4']) && isset($_POST['info5']) && isset($_POST['info6'])) {
            // check if both fields are set
            //open file in read mode to get number of lines
            $handle = fopen($txt, 'r');
            //check file opened

            if($handle) {
                //get number of lines
                $count = 1;
                while(fgets($handle) !== false) {
                    $count++;
                }

                fclose($handle);
                //open in append mode.
                $handle = fopen($txt, 'a');
                //prepare data to be writen
                $txt = $count . ' ' . $_POST['info1'].'/'.$_POST['info2'].'/'.$_POST['info3'].'/'.$_POST['info4'].'/'.$_POST['info5'].'/'.$_POST['info6']. "\r\n";
                //write data to file
                fwrite($handle,$txt);
                fclose($handle);
            }

        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on and display_errors in development? If the file handle can't be opened for writing, such as because of bad permissions on the directory or existing file, you'll see the error. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` _always_ in development.

Comment: It would seem you're fairly new to Stack Overflow, so welcome first of all! Secondly, this site is mainly designed to help you overcome programming problems when you hit a rough spot and can't get past it. To get high quality answers, be sure to post what you've tried, what result you're currently getting, and what the desired result is. You haven't shown what steps you've taken to attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that either one or more of your `$_POST` variables isn't set or there is a permission issue.  Check if you are getting into the if statement by printing something if you get into it, and also check to make sure the user running php has write permission in the given directory.

Answer (score 1):

In `fopen` function `mode` param with value `r` doesn't make file being created.
See [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) documentation.

Also the issue could be write permissions for user that runs that PHP script.

These is only my guesses. Anyway you should configure your PHP (in dev environment) to show you every error/warning in order to debug such issues. You can do that in `php.ini` file or straight in PHP file with this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are first trying to open the file read only, and if that succeeds you close it and open it again with write access.

This will only work if the file already exists.

If the file doesn't exist, your text will not get written to it.

Move the closing bracket if `if ($handle) {` in front of the second `fopen` call.

```
        if($handle) {
            //get number of lines
            $count = 1;
            while(fgets($handle) !== false) {
                $count++;
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
        //open in append mode.
        $handle = fopen($txt, 'a');
        //prepare data to be writen
        $txt = $count . ' ' . $_POST['info1'].'/'.$_POST['info2'].'/'.$_POST['info3'].'/'.$_POST['info4'].'/'.$_POST['info5'].'/'.$_POST['info6']. "\r\n";
        //write data to file
        fwrite($handle,$txt);
        fclose($handle);
```

by the way, you can reduce this to three lines of code.

```
$lines = file($txt);
$count = sizeof($lines);
file_put_contents($txt, $count . ' ' . $_POST['info1'].'/'.$_POST['info2'].'/'.$_POST['info3'].'/'.$_POST['info4'].'/'.$_POST['info5'].'/'.$_POST['info6']. "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: `fopen` with `r` option will only throw a warning if the file doesn't exist and `fopen` with option `a` will attempt to create the file if it doesn't exist, so the code posted should attempt to create the file with 2nd `fopen`

Answer (score 0):

to check for multiple variables in `isset` create only one `isset` to check all veriables

change  this

```
 if(isset($_POST['info1']) && isset($_POST['info2']) && isset($_POST['info3']) && isset($_POST['info4']) && isset($_POST['info5']) && isset($_POST['info6']))
```

to

```
 if(isset($_POST['info1'],$_POST['info2'],$_POST['info3'],$_POST['info4'],$_POST['info5'],$_POST['info6']))
```